# How to change max-height of the column panel in DataGrid component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to modify the max-height of a column panel that opens when clicking the "Columns" button within the Toolbar component used in the DataGrid. I'm using an older version of @material-ui/data-grid: "^4.0.0-alpha.8".

[image: Image of the column panel]

I've tried creating a custom component using GridColumnPanel, but I'm unable to change its styling. How can I effectively reduce the max-height to a smaller value so that it doesn't affect the overall page height?

Here's my code:

```
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridToolbarContainer,
  GridToolbarColumnsButton,
  GridColumnsPanel,
} from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  columnsPanel: {
    maxHeight: '282px',
  }
}));

const CustomColumnsPanel = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <GridColumnsPanel className={classes.columnsPanel}>{children}</GridColumnsPanel>;
};

const TableList = ({ ...props }) => {
  // ... rest of the code ...

  return (
    <Box>
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        components={{
          Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
          ColumnsPanel: CustomColumnsPanel
        }}
      />
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `components` prop, use the `slots` prop and pass the props for the panel in the `slotProps` like so -

```ts
<DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: {
              pageSize: 5
            }
          }
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5]}
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
        slotProps={{
          panel: { sx: { "& .MuiPaper-root": { maxHeight: "200px" } } }
        }}
      />
```

Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-galileo-v9gwk2).

Comment: That does work just fine on MUI V5 I guess. The project I'm working on is still using V4 so the slots prop does not apply. But thanks anyway! Guess I'll need to migrate to V5 

Comment: In v4, you should be able to use `components` and `componentsProps` to achieve the same result. Check [docs](https://v4.mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#props).

Comment: Actually, it did not work using componentsProps as mentioned in the docs and I think it was because I was using a very old version but decided not to dig deeper because updating to the latest version of Mui seemed to be a better choice, Thank you for your help!